# How to calculate the data transmission rate with path-loss?

Tags: communication-complexity, shannon

We aim to calculate the data transmission rate when sending results from the server back to the user's device. Using the notation:

- ( B_v ): wireless bandwidth of the server
- ( P_v ): server's transmission power
- ( D ): Distance

$$ r_{vi} = B_v \log_2 \left( 1 + \frac{P_v |h|^2}{\omega_0 D \theta_{vi}} \right)$$

\begin{align*}
\text{Parameters for Shannon’s formula:} \\
\bullet & \text{ Path loss exponent } \theta = 2.5 \\
\bullet & \text{ Channel fading coefficient } h = 0.7 \\
\bullet & \text{ White Gaussian noise power } \omega_0 = 3 \times 10^{13}
\end{align*}

Given that the path loss is included in the denominator in the Shannon formula*, is this the correct formula and parameters values to determine the data transmission rate?

- Luo, Quyuan, et al. "Resource scheduling in edge computing: A survey." IEEE Communications Surveys & Tutorials 23.4 (2021): 2131-2165.